# Cells are not formatting as per styling Xlsx-Styles Angular 4

Tags: angular, js-xlsx

I have to export an excel sheet through my angular app. So I am using js-xlsx and xlsx-style modules. I would like to format the cells as I required but am not able to.
The below is the piece of code using for styling the cell.

```
cell.s = {font: { bold: true }};
```

While debugging the sheet has font styling properties but while exporting the excel doesn't render the properties.

[image]

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better understand your question. An example on [SlackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) would be ideal.

Comment: @Viqas here is the sample in stackblitz [StackblitzSample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xukeq2)

Comment: @thecrusader Did you get this working?

Comment: If someone can find the answer, please post it here